# Sending mail from Java to users with international characters in their Notes username

Tags: xpages

I'm sending mails from a Java bean ([the email bean from Tony McGuckin](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter)).

I have users with international characters in their Notes name (the Danish æ, ø and å). Something goes wrong when passing the Notes name to the Java bean .setSendTo() method, with the result that the email bean is unable to send the mail. The Java exception states:

```
NotesException: Unable to send mail, no match found in Name & Address Book(s)
```

I am also seeing the issue in the subject of the mail if subject contains international characters.

How can I ensure that the international characters work with the Java bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [MimeUtility](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html). Specifically encodeWord or encodeText.

E.g.

```
MimeUtility.encodeWord( sendToAddress )
```

Comment: Thank you, Tommy. I extended the email bean to encode the parameters and now it works.